# How to set marging to long text in Label which is divided into two lines

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a Label in my AbsoluteLayout and when that Label's text is long in puts text into two lines which is okay but is it possible to get a Margin to the second left wrapped line too? I attached image to show better what I mean and in that Image there is Red arrow showing the place what I'm asking.

Thanks for All!

[image]

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="Center"
      VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="Start">
        <Image HeightRequest="160" 
               HorizontalOptions="Start" 
               WidthRequest="360" 
               Aspect="AspectFill" 
               Grid.Row="0"  
               Source="{Binding EnclosureUrl}" 
               Margin="0,0,0,15">                            
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TappedItemCommand"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding Link}"
                                      NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>                            
        </Image>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               Margin="0,0,0,40"
               WidthRequest="250"
               Style="{StaticResource BoldBasicText}"
               Font="Bold,20"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,-1,-1"
               BackgroundColor="{x:Static ownStyles:StyleSettings.colCaptionColorFade}"
               TextColor="{x:Static StyleSettings:Settings.colRed}"
               Text="{Binding Header}">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TappedItemCommand"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding Link}"
                                      NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />                                               
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Line Break Mode available in Xamarin.Forms:-

LineBreakMode="WordWrap"

```
<Label Text="{Binding Certification, StringFormat='Board Certification:{0:F0}'}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
```

Refer Link Below:-

[Xamarin Text Line Break Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155724/label-wrapping-with-stacklayout)

[Label wrapping with StackLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155724/label-wrapping-with-stacklayout)

Comment: Thanks but LineBreakMode="WordWrap" doesn't seem to work if Label is in Grid and RelativeLayout... Why in earth...
Are there any other possibilities to solve this?